# Configure JAXB marshaller to use child class instead of parent without using annotations

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, jaxb

I generate classes from soap schema that uses types extention and by default JAXB marshalls only in parent class. Part of soap message I have problem with:

```
<Value i:type="StringValue">
  <Value>Text</Value>
</Value>
```

Parent class that is currently use by JAXB

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ParameterValueBase")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    BoolValue.class,
    NumberValue.class,
    StringValue.class,
    DateTimeValue.class,
    TimeOfDayValue.class,
    ListValue.class,
    DurationValue.class,
    DiscountPeriodValue.class
})
public class ParameterValueBase
{

}
```

Child class I want it to marshal to

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "StringValue", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class StringValue
    extends ParameterValueBase
    implements ToString2
{

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Value", namespace = "http://schemas.sitels.ru/FORIS/IL/ResourceInformation", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<String> value;

/**
 * Gets the value of the value property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 *     
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

}

I expected that I can cast ParameterValueBase to StringValue. But it gives ClassCastException. So it seems I have to marshal that message part right into StringValue. In questions with JAXB inheritance most answers advice manually added annotations. I can't use it because ParameterValueBase and StringValue are generated classes. So the right way would be to somehow configure JAXB marshaller. How can I do that?

Marshaller bean:

```
@Bean()
public Jaxb2Marshaller resourceMarshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("...");
    return marshaller;
}
```

Edit: I found out that when I simply copy paste soap response as string and process it with Jaxb2Marshaller without running the whole app it actually creates an instance of StringValue. But when I'm running it as spring boot ws via WebServiceGatewaySupport for some reason it creates an instance of ParameterBaseValue. I'm not sure what the reason might be

Comment: What namespace is "i:" in the xml snippet

Comment: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Comment: Without the http://? it should be `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`